# Magmi: Import group price based on customer group

Tags: csv, magento, import, magmi

I'm trying to import some group prices based on client group.

I have something like this:

```
Customer Group: Common Clients
Customer Group: Registered
```

I want to have two different prices based on customer group, I can do it on group prices section on the Magento product admin, but I need to import a batch of products using Magmi, others fields, works great, sku, price, special_price...

I have added to my csv this columns:

```
group_price:Common Clients, group_price:Registered
60,43
```

I'm also using Group Item Processor plugin: https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/magmi-grouped-price-plugin

Following this tutorial: https://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-group-price-importer/
 but it did not work.

But the group price it is not being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just upgraded to Magmi v0.7.19a trying to import group_price

The first attempt did not work either. Then I tried to use a . (dot) instead of a comma (,) in the group_price separator and the magic happened. I guess it is some php typo in the file grouppriceprocessor.php.

Note: I use the comma as decimal mark in prices. My .csv file looks like this:

```
| sku  | price  | group_price:groupName   |
___________________________________________
| 1234 | 26,5   | 15.99                   |
```

PS: Also don't forget to add a checkmark in the **itemprocessors section** of Magmi:

x Group Price Importer v0.0.1

Comment: Sorry Obsidian, the question was " Following this tutorial: https://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-group-price-importer/ but it did not work." I just showed how it worked for me... so, " the does not really answer the question.." is not really adding any value here!

Comment: I was abble to solve the issue using the new version of Magmi...and the Group Price processor...thank you anyway.

Comment: The checkmark for Group Price Importer was what I needed! It's an easy to use function when this is check!